Does the SubstituteUser Session really exist?
I'm working on some functionality that would apply rules conditionally based on the session type.
However, when I try logging in as a community user and look at the results of the getCurrentSession() method call, the session type is 'chatter networks' and not 'SubstituteUser'.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_session_types.htm&type=5 would have had me thinking it would be 'SubstituteUser'. Is this only for logging in as a 'typical' Salesforce licensed user?
